# Extract URL using beautifulsoup 4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract a URL using BS4, I can get to the correct location but I'm not sure how to remove the '' tags from URL. I tried adding .text however this just returned nothing.

```
vid_screenshot = (soup('a', {'class':'mp4Thumb'}))[0].contents[0]

>> <img src="www.fgfg.com/dsfasdf.jpg"/>

desired result
>> www.fgfg.com/dsfasdf.jpg
```

did not work, returned nothing.

```
(soup('a', {'class':'mp4Thumb'}))[0].contents[0].text
```

Would anyone know how to strip these tags..?

Comment: What about `vid_screenshot = (soup('a', {'class':'mp4Thumb'}))[0].contents[0]['src']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the HTML tag, you need to take the `src` attribute:

```
vid_screenshot = soup('a', {'class':'mp4Thumb'})[0].contents[0]
vid_screenshot_src = wid_screenshot['src']
```

This assumes there is always going to be a `src` attribute on the tag. You can also use the `.get()` method to return `None` if the attribute is not present:

```
vid_screenshot = soup('a', {'class':'mp4Thumb'})[0].contents[0]
vid_screenshot_src = wid_screenshot.get('src')
```

or you can give `.get()` a second argument to return if the attribute is missing:

```
vid_screenshot = soup('a', {'class':'mp4Thumb'})[0].contents[0]
vid_screenshot_src = wid_screenshot.get('src', 'default value')
```

See the [Attributes documentation section](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes).